# UnauthorizedAccessException: Reading a file

Tags: c#, io

I know that this exception happens when you are trying to write to a file that is read only, but I am not doing that. I am trying to just read the contents of that file and do something with that data. But I am still getting `UnAuthorizedAccessException`. This piece of code was working perfectly before I upgraded the version of the software I program in and the windows reinstallation I did on my laptop.

Here is my code sample.

```
private void CreateColorValueField2D()
{
  float[,] data = GetMeshColorValuesFromRhino();
  for (int i = 0; i < columns; i++)
  {
    for (int j = 0; j < rows; j++)
    {
      scalarField[i, j].ScalarValueRules = data[i, j];
    }
  }
} 

private float[,] GetMeshColorValuesFromRhino()
{
  float[,] dataArray = new float[columns, rows];
  string[] lines = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(SimulationManager.Get().ImportToUnityInterpolatedFieldFilePath); // LINE WERE CODE BUGS OUT
  var linesArray = Make2DArray(lines, columns, rows);

  for (int i = 0; i < columns; i++)
  {
    for (int j = 0; j < rows; j++)
    {
      dataArray[i, j] = float.Parse(linesArray[i, j]);
    }
  }
  return dataArray;
}
```

Comment: "What are  all possible and plausible reasons for UnAuthorizedAccessException" (which is essentially what this post asks) is way too broad for SO. Please provide [MCVE] including all necessary data inline in the post and details about the file you trying to read (i.e. can you open it with notepad not running as admin).

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov Its just a simple .txt file

Comment: Ok I solved it, it was a careless typo in the file path